# Prove that the 23 people have the same weight.

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

I know that it must be an old question, and I have encountered it before, in MAT 1993.2 (Oxford admission test). But I dimly remember the solution.
The question is

> Twenty-three people, each with integral weight, decide to play football, separating into two teams of 11 people each, plus a referee. To keep things fair, the teams chosen must have equal total weight. It turns out that no matter who is chosen to be the referee, this can always be done. Prove that the 23 people have the same weight.

Comment: However dimly you seem to remember the solution, write it down.

Comment: I like the discuss that I found on [this page](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/105400/extending-an-assignment-property-from-q-to-r-or-c).

Comment: sounds like pigeonholes

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The answers above rely mostly on the fact that the weights are integers. However, the result also holds for real weights as well, and is a common (spectacular regardless, in my opinion) application of linear algebra.

Let $W$ be the column vector of weights. Consider the matrix $A$ ($23 \times 23$ with entries in $\{0,1,-1\}$) such that its $i$th row represents the weight distribution of the teams ($1$ for a team, $-1$ for the other and $A_{i,i}=0$ is the only null entry) when person $i$ is a referee.

Then $AW=0$, so $A$ has rank at most $22$ (unless $W=0$).

Besides, in $\mathbb{F}_2$, $A$ reduces to $A’$ which has only $1$ outside the diagonal and $0$ in the diagonal.

We can check that the cofactor $(1,1)$ of $A’$ is nonzero in $\mathbb{F}_2$, so $A$ has a nonzero cofactor, so its rank is exactly $22$.

Now, $W$ and $(1,1,\ldots,1)$ are in the kernel of $A$. Thus they are proportional, which is the required claim.

Comment: This is a super nice approach... but how is it obvious that the cofactor $(1,1)$ of $A'$ is non-zero in $F_2$?  If I understand you correctly, that cofactor is that determinant of $A'$ with first row and first column removed, so it looks exactly like $A'$ except "smaller" (size $22 \times 22$), but you're saying $det(A' \ size\ 23) = 0$ while $det(smaller \ A' \ size \ 22) =1$, so this probably has to do with parity(?)...  But how do you prove / visualize that?

Comment: @antkam : A nice determinant identity is $\det(I+uv^T)=1+v^Tu$. In this case $u=v=e$, vectors containing only $1$ as components. $e^Te$ is the dimension $n$, so in $\Bbb F_2$ this gives determinant equal to $n-1\pmod 2$.

Comment: @LutzL - thanks!  About 10 mins after I commented, I also proved it differently: If $A'_{size \ k} v = 0$, this can happen if $v = $all $1$s iff $k$ is odd, and this cannot happen at all if $v \neq$ all $1$s because in the product some rows $=j$ and some $=j-1$ where $j =$ no. of $1$s in $v$.  But your identity is much quicker.

Comment: @antkam: as in a few similar problems, the argument is to add all of the columns to the first column, which becomes filled with ones, and then you substract the new first column from every other column. Then you get a lower-triangular matrix with 1s on the diagonal.

Comment: @Mindlack - oh nice!  in this case for size $22$ the sum of all columns $=$ all $1$s, and after subtracting you get the identity matrix, proving full rank _dramatically_.  :)  intuitive and easy to remember.

Comment: "above"?  :)  Don't mention relative position of answers, they can change.

Comment: "However, the result also holds for real weights as well, and is a common (spectacular regardless, in my opinion) application of linear algebra."
Your argument depends on reducing the weights in F_2, which you can't do in general for real numbers. How do you extend it to all real numbers then?

Comment: I am not reducing the weights in $\mathbb{F}_2$. I am reducing the team-description matrix, of which the only entroes are $0$ (on the diagonal only), $1$ and $-1$.

Comment: Is this possible to explain without matrix. My students are n high school and the are familiar only with independance and dot product in vectors space $F^n$.

Comment: Uh... consider the team-assignment vectors (so the rows of $A$). As $AW=0$, they’re all in the orthogonal of $W$ so they can’t be linearly independent (for dimension reasons). However, assume that they don’t span the orthogonal space of $W$. Then the $22$ first vectors are not linearly independent, and in particular their $22$ first coordinates aren’t linearly independent in $\mathbb{Q}$, so in $\mathbb{Z}$, so in $\mathbb{F}_2$. But it’s easy to see (adapting that “sum argument”) to show that the mod $2$ reduction of the upper left cofactor is nonzero, so that we get a contradiction (cont’d).

Comment: @Aqua: see the comment above for the start. Thus the team-assignment vectors span a vector space of dimension $22$ and are contained in the orthogonals of $W$ and of the “full-one” vector. So $W$ and the “full-one” vector must have the same orthogonal spaces and thus be proportional. QED. These are pretty advanced high-school students you’re teaching!

Comment: Any way, $W$ is in $\mathbb{R}^{23}$? And how can I do mod 2 reduction with coefficents when doing linear indpendece if I don't have $W$ in rationals?

Comment: $W$ is in $\mathbb{R}^{23}$, but $A$ is an integer-valued matrix. $A_{i,j}$ is $0$ if $i=j$, and $\pm 1$ otherwise ($+1$ corresponds to one of the groups when you divide all the weights but the $j$-th one into two $11$-element subsets, $-1$ to the other). Since $AW=0$, $A$ cannot be invertible (ie its determinant is zero, so is zero in any field), so its row/column vectors cannot be linearly independent in any field.

Comment: Yes, yes, but when doing indpendeance without matrix

Comment: The precise reasoning is: the matrix has rank $\leq 22$ in $\mathbb{R}$. Now you can show the vector equivalent of $(A_{i,j})_{1 \leq i,j \leq 22}$ being invertible in $\mathbb{F}_2$, which implies that these (reduced) vectors are linearly independent in $\mathbb{Z}^{22}$ over $\mathbb{Z}$, so they’re independent over $\mathbb{Q}$. So you can construct a matrix inverse in $\mathbb{Q}$, so your vectors must be independent in $\mathbb{R}$. So $A$ has rank exactly $22$ in $\mathbb{R}$ so its kernel has rank exactly one. But its kernel contains $1$ and $W$ so $W$ is a multiple of $1$.

Comment: I understand solution with matrix. But this transition makes me unsure.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question starting in “So, if”. Again, here is the argument: let $a_i$ be the rows of $A$. They span a space of dimension at most $22$ since $AW=0$. Let $b_i$ be made with the $22$ first coefficients of $a_i$, and $c_i$ be its reduction mod $2$. Now, you can show that the $c_i$ generate $\mathbb{F}_2^{22}$ so they are linearly independent on $\mathbb{F}_2$. (cont’d)

Comment: So if $Z$ is the space of integer-valued vectors $z$ with $z \cdot b_i=0$ for each $i$, then by infinite descent $Z=0$ and the $b_i$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Z}$, so over $\mathbb{Q}$, so the same holds for the $a_i$, $i < 23$. Now (and here is perhaps the part you’re asking about) the space of vectors $z$ such that $a_i \cdot z=0$ for each $i$ has the same dimension in $\mathbb{Q}$ and in $\mathbb{R}$. In particular, the $a_i$, $i < 23$, are linearly independent in $\mathbb{R}$ and the conclusion follows.

Comment: @Aqua: does that help you?

Answer (score 6):

Proof by contradiction.

Let there be such a collection of 23 people and with unequal weights.

Then, there is the total weight of $W$, and that is made up of everyone's individual weights $w$. And so, $W=w_1+w_2+w_3 \dots w_{21}+w_{22}+w_{23}$. Let this be the "smallest total weight".

Then let's try to find a smaller total weight. (We shouldn't be able to, however).

To start, all integer weights $w$ are either even or odd. And since one person is referee, then let's see what happens to the weights that are divided into the two teams.

If $w_n$ is referee, then we'd have $W-w_n$ as the remaining weights. Regardless of $w_n$ being even or odd, this remaining weights would have to be even since it's split between two teams.

Now that means that $(W-w_n)+(W-w_m)$ should be even regardless of of $w_n$ or $w_m$ is even or odd... but $(W-w_n)+(W-w_m)=2W-w_n-w_m$ could be odd if, say, $w_n$ was even and $w_m$ was odd. So this means we're looking at all $w$'s being all even, or all odd.

So, all $w$'s are of the same parity.

If all $w$'s are even, when we could have a smaller total weight, $W'$, by simply dividing everyone's weight by 2, and this would be smaller than $W$ - but we assumed at the beginning that $W$ was the smallest --> Contradiction.

If all $w$'s are odd, then we could get another smaller total weight, $W''$, by adding $1$ to everyone's weight and then dividing by $2$ - but, again, we assumed that $W$ was the smallest --> Contradiction.

Comment: If all weights are equal, then your last argument surely is still true: they are all even or odd, and you can find a smallest minimal weights (I'm not sure, however, what is the physical meaning of "dividing" the weights of the people). I'm not convinced by your proof - or there is something that I do not understand

Comment: @FlorianIngels I think the proof in this answer is correct. If a set of players has the desired property, then the set of players still has the property if you add a constant to everyone's weight (team weights always go up by 11*the constant) or if you multiply everyone's weight by a constant (team weights scale by same constant). So you can do either of the reductions in the last two paragraphs. In the last paragraph we also need the argument that (w+1)/2 is less than w for all w > 1, and we should assume for contradiction that all the weights are unequal.

Comment: (in other words, @Sat has produced an algorithm, given a bunch of weights with the desired property such that not all are equal to each other, to produce a bunch of weights with the desired property and strictly smaller total sum such that not all are equal to each other. This implies that such a collection of weights cannot exist. You are right that the algorithm applies in the case that all weights are equal which would seem to invalidate the proof, except the algorithm breaks on (1, 1, ..., 1) (doesn't make these weights smaller), which should be pointed out.)

Comment: @hunter : The algorithm does not have to work in the case $w_i = 1$ for all $i$ since that is the conclusion we wish to draw: "all the weights are equal".  The contradiction is to the second paragraph's "and with unequal weights".

Comment: @EricTowers I totally agree!